# IOS - My Data Usage keeps returning data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a recursive call that uses NSURLSession, this recursive call runs every 2 seconds but what is happening is that when there is no data coming back from server, my Network Usage is still used and even though no data is returning i get 1kb or less being used every time this recursive called is made.

How can i stop this from happening?

is there a way?

can this not be done?

is this because the http headers is coming back?

will this be rejected if a submit the app to Apple?

If you ask, i will edit and give code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, sending a request uses data, even if no results come back.

Asking for data every two seconds seems excessive. Maybe just reduce the frequency of checking? Or perhaps you could switch it around so new data is *pushed* to the client rather than polling like this? Or maybe you could build heuristics to better predict when data *will* be there?

Why would Apple reject an app that accesses the network?

Comment: I thought Apple would reject because of the polling every 2 seconds as users data usage my be used up even when there is no data coming back. Thanks for replying

Comment: I might just poll every 2 minutes, would that be a better way?

Comment: i would have a better bet using an application server, this is something i will think about later on